# Toggle checkboxes in a tab based upon master checkbox selection

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I'm having issues with an onclick event for a checkbox in a vba form. Basically what I am trying to do is ammend the value of all checkboxes on specific tab to be the same value as a master checkbox. In this instance, it is the 'Use Online' captioned checkbox below (online_toggle in the code) which once clicked should toggle the other checkboxes on the tab 'on' or 'off'. I currently have the following code but it keeps producing an error at 'For Each obj In online.OLEObjects'

[image: My user form]

```
Private Sub online_toggle_Click()

Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(6).Controls

    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        If ctl.GroupName = "online_variants" Then
        If ctl.Name <> "online_toggle" Then
            ctl.Value = online_toggle.Value
        End If
        End If
    End If

Next ctl

End Sub
```

N.B. online is the name of the tab on which all of the checkboxes are situated. If it helps the checkboxes affected by the master checkbox are all grouped as online_variants

Cheers,

Jason

Comment: Is that a Multipage that you are using OR A Tabstrip?

Comment: I think it's a tabstrip. If it helps, the checkboxes that need to be altered are grouped under the name online_variants.

Comment: In that case I think it is a Multipage. In design time, in a Tabstrip the controls in Tab1 are visible in Tab2 as well whereas in the Multipage when you switch between tabs you can see independent controls...

Comment: In that case it is a multipage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a Mutipage the page numbering starts from 0 so if you are trying to refer to the Checkboxes in the `Online` tab (7th Tab) then use this

```
Dim ctl As Control

For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(6).Controls
    If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
        '~~> Your code here
        Debug.Print ctl.Name
    End If
Next
```

Comment: If i've understood you correctly, this is now the code I have in there: Private Sub online_toggle_Click()
Dim ctl As Control
 
    For Each ctl In Me.MultiPage1.Pages(6).Controls

        If TypeOf ctl Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
            If ctl.Name <> "online_toggle" Then
                ctl.Object.Value = online.online_toggle.Value
            End If
        End If
 
    Next ctl
End Sub - This doesn't work though.

Comment: `ctl.Object.Value = online.online_toggle.Value` is incorrect. You can use `Ctl.Value` and instead of this directly use the checkbox name for example `Ctl.Value = online_toggle.Value`

Comment: That's great. It has now solved the problem however, as I am going to have multiple master checkboxes on a tab I only want those assigned to a specified group to be affected by the toggle. I'm guessing it's just another IF condition refering to group in some way?

Comment: Nevermind. I've found out myself. I've ammended the code above. Thanks for the responses.

Comment: Gr8... Had stepped out for sometime :)