# Why do Labels get Type mismatch errors in VBA but ComboBoxes don't?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm running Excel 2003. I have the following VBA code, corresponding to a simple `UserForm` comprising a `ComboBox` control and a `Label` control. It works through the save of the `ComboBox` but generates a *Type mismatch* error when saving the `Label`.

```
Private whatComboBox As ComboBox
Private whatLabel As Label

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call SaveComboBox(SomeComboBox)
    Call SaveLabel(SomeLabel)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveComboBox(aComboBox As ComboBox)
    Set whatComboBox = aComboBox
End Sub

Private Sub SaveLabel(aLabel As Label)
    Set whatLabel = aLabel
End Sub
```

[And I do appreciate that VBA is limited in comparison to most other languages. But I wouldn't have thought this was the kind of thing it would get wrong.]

Thanks all!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
Private whatComboBox As msforms.ComboBox
Private whatLabel As msforms.Label

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call SaveComboBox(SomeComboBox)
    Call SaveLabel(SomeLabel)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveComboBox(aComboBox As msforms.ComboBox)
    Set whatComboBox = aComboBox
End Sub

Private Sub SaveLabel(aLabel As msforms.Label)
    Set whatLabel = aLabel
End Sub
```

Regarding your query

> It works through the save of the ComboBox but generates a Type mismatch error when saving the Label.

You must qualify the Label object because Excel also has an object named Label

**Alternative**

```
Private whatComboBox As Control
Private whatLabel As Control

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Call SaveComboBox(SomeComboBox)
    Call SaveLabel(SomeLabel)
End Sub

Private Sub SaveComboBox(aComboBox As Control)
    Set whatComboBox = aComboBox
End Sub

Private Sub SaveLabel(aLabel As Control)
    Set whatLabel = aLabel
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent! That was it, and thank you for explaining it so clearly!

Comment: A related question, if one uses Control as the declared type: How does one cast in VBA? For example, if I have declared everything as a Control but I need to invoke ComboBox-specific methods, what do I have to do? (Or does VBA dynamically determine the validity of the method invocation based on the actual type of object rather than its declared type?)

Comment: @Richard: You have to use `TypeOf`. See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309825/toggle-checkboxes-in-a-tab-based-upon-master-checkbox-selection